# Apache CXF web service as a Tapestry5 module for integration with a .Net client

Tags: jax-ws, cxf, tapestry

**Environment:**

- **Servlet container:** Apache Tomcat 7
- **Java web\IoC framework:** Apache Tapestry 5.3.6
- **Web service framework:** Apache CXF 2.7.3

**Requirements**

I need to provide a web-service for a `.Net` client (i.e. `C#`). This web service should be able to utilize `Tapestry`'s IoC framework to be able to use it's Registry to automatically initialize `Tapestry` configured services (i.e. Utility services)

**Current Progress**

I'm very new to `jax-ws` but after some reading from the `Apache CXF` documentations, I'm trying to mimic the following [sample](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/cxf/trunk/distribution/src/main/release/samples/java_first_jaxws/).
So I developed a simple service without an interface, successful executed the following command:

```
java2ws -wsdl -server -verbose -o IpkWS.wsdl -databinding aegis -portname IxAccess -address http://localhost:8080/ipk-ws -servicename IpkWS -frontend jaxws -soap12 -s ws_build -d ws_resources com.sc.ipk.ws.services.Calculator
```

Which created a `wsdl` file and the `Endpoint` class. According to the sample linked above, I still need to define the `CXFServlet` in my `web.xml` file. And still have to create the `cxf-servlet.xml` file.

**Questions**

1. I know how to write a `Tapestry` module but how should I do it with web-services ?

   - Is it possible to configure `CXFServlet` without permanently having it in my web app's `web.xml` file ? I should be free not to include `CXFServlet` in my `web.xml` file because It's very possible that I do not deploy this module for other clients.
   - What are the minimum needed `Apache CXF`/`JAX-WS` libraries I need for my web-service to run on `Apache Tomcat 7` ?
2. Do I **need** the `cxf-servlet.xml` file ? What is it for ?
3. Are there any needed configurations to enable the `.Net` client to consume my service ? If yes, would that affect\stop other client platforms from consuming my web-service properly ?
4. What purpose does the `Endpoint` class created by `java2ws` serve ? Is it's `main` method executed by the `CXFServlet` ?
5. What does the I'll have to return a complex collection of `Java` objects, should that be ok with a `.Net` client ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be a little bit out of topic, but Tynamo's team dealt great job with Jax-RS integration in Tapetry: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/TYNAMO/tapestry-resteasy+guide
If you don't really nead a WSDL, it could help you.

If you definitely want to use Jax-WS, here somes "thoughts" : http://tapestry.1045711.n5.nabble.com/Web-services-using-Tapestry-td4974432.html

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, the thing is that I'm new to `jax-ws` and I find derkoe's code hard to grasp. However, I downloaded `Metro`'s src and javadocs and hopefully derkoe's code will be easier to understand now. Thanks again :)

Comment: Sadly I went with derkoe's code. I'm sad because I wanted to use `Apache CXF` so I don't have to deal with `JAXB` limitations. Thank you Jean.